# Too many layers of indirection, is this too many?

Tags: .net, abstraction

I was just wondering if this would be to many layers of indirection?

[Alt text http://img244.imageshack.us/img244/7371/classdiagram1.jpg](http://img244.imageshack.us/img244/7371/classdiagram1.jpg)

I try and do a little bit of explaining. The idea is that I am building a API over the top of a COM object which only exposes Do and Eval methods.

Previously I have just passed a IComObject into the Table class and work directly against that however that means when I try and test the Table class I have mock the IComObject and worry about the commands getting sent to the COM object in my table class.

The basic idea is that I have command runners that are responsible for calling the right commands in the COM object, and the Table (and others) object just talk to the command runners, not having to worry about the commands being executed. Then in my tests I can do this:

```
Mock<TableCommandRunner> mockrunner = new Mock<TableCommandRunner>();
mockrunner.Setup(run => run.getName("DummyTable")).Returns("FakeName");

Table table = new Table("DummyTable");
//Table.Name just calls commandrunner.getName
Assert.Equal(table.Name,"FakeName");
```

Are there too many layers of indirection or would this be OK?

NOTE: I will have a lot more classes then just Table, things like Map, Window, Object, etc. that would all talk to the command runners.

Comment: I think this question is a bit subjective, perhaps consider re-phrasing it.

Comment: The image link is broken.

Answer (score 7):

The question you need to ask is, does this additional abstraction solve some problem you had before adding it, and is the complexity of the abstraction acceptable to you? When to abstract is a pretty subjective decision...as is often said, abstracting can solve almost any problem, but at the cost of greater complexity.

If you are asking this question, it seems your questioning the value of the additional complexity this abstraction brings to the table. It doesn't look terribly complicated given your diagram, and if it does indeed solve a problem you were having before...I would say go with it.

Ultimately, go with your instincts...abstract when necessary, but avoid it if you can.

Comment: I'd add: start with the least amount of abstraction possible, and only add more if you really need it. (YAGNI)

Comment: Well it does make developing the higher class objects like Table, Map, Window, Object etc a lot easier because they don't have to worry about the commands getting run only the result thus meaning easier to mock the tablecommandrunner rather then the strings needed for IComObject.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's too many levels of abstraction.  Your solution looks quite elegant to me because you are simply testing that the Table class calls the right ComandRunner functions. You are testing how the Table class deals with the CommandRunner, and you have removed all the complications of the CommandRunner implementations including the IComObject.   This is what Mocking is all about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but for me, when in doubt, I always like to provide shortcut convenient methods that wrap this kind of abstraction.

Something like

```
void runCommand(string cmd) // objects instantiated and used inside
```

so even if I have too much abstraction, there's still a straight-forward way to just "do it dammit".